# PT-Kill not logging to file

Tags: percona-tools

Run command for pt-kill

```
/usr/bin/pt-kill --ignore-state User lock --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --daemonize --busy-time 10 --kill --print --log /var/log/pt-kill.log h=HOST,u=master,p=PaSS,P=3306
```

Queries are killed but not logged. Runs as root on Amazon Linux and file /var/log/put-kill.log exists and has 600 permissions

Answer (score 1):

The command seems right.

You can try to debug using `PTDEBUG`:

```
PTDEBUG=1 (your complete pt-kill command with daemonize and log ) 2>/var/log/pt-kill.err
```

Be careful to watch disk space; don't let it run in debug mode indefinitely.

Comment: I am on amazon linux and had to use sudo for the command (even as root user) and I also updated rc.local